# Loop over months in C

Tags: c

Currently I am having 2 variables storing year month in it.

**Example:**

> var1 : 201711
>
> var2 : 201801

Firstly I want to find if both the months in the variable are consecutive year months or not. If not then I would like create a loop so that I can get the months between var1&2.

```
if( MonthsDifference(var2,var1) = 1 )
{
    ....
}
else
{
     for ( a = 1 ; a <= MonthsDifference(var2 - var1) ; a++)
     {
           printf("Next month is:[%d]",addmonths(var1,1));
     }
}
```

I am having trouble imagining a logic to get the Months difference & also to add months effectively. Value type & data(year-month) stored in var1 & 2 is flexible and can be in any way preferable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of var1/var2?

Comment: tag with [esperanto]

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Currently it is int however we can use char/double as well, which ever is preferable for the calculations.

Comment: @purec Sorry I cant understand your request.

Comment: From `var` as `int` you can extract year with `var/100` and month with `var%100`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Not sure if you've chosen the right data type tbh. It might probably be wises to use the standard `struct tm` which could be produced from the standard function `gettime("time string here")`, or `time_t` which is in seconds since the epoch (1/1/1970). Adding a month to a `struct tm fubar` would be  `fubar.tm_month++; fubar.tm_year += fubar.tm_month / 12; fubar.tm_month %= 12;`, much easier than `time_t` (call `gmtime` to convert `time_t` to `struct tm`, add the month as per above and then `mktime` to get that back to `time_t`)... `int` is not guaranteed to be able to store values above `32767`

Comment: @user1989425 I agree, but I am getting the data from an oracle DB and so its much more convenient to fetch it into int. Can you please elaborate on your last statement ? `int` is currently storing my 201701 value.. In which case is it not guaranteed to store it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventional to iterate over a list is

```
for (var = first_item; end_not_reached(var); var = next_after(var))
```

Your encoding has the correct order of dates, i.e. `var1 <= var2` when `var1` is earlier than `var2`. Therefore, to check whether you've reached the end of the list, all you need to do is compare the iterator with the end date.

The next month after a given date is given by the following function:

```
int next_month(int date) {
    return date % 100 == 12 ? date + 89 : date + 1;
}
```

Thus:

```
if (next_month(var1) == var2)
    ... // the months are consecutive with var1 just before var2

for (var = var1; var <= var2; var = next_month(var)) {
    …
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the encoding scheme for years and months in your two variables are:

```
combined_value = year * 100 + month
```

So the lower two decimal digits are the month, the upper digits (typically 4) are the year. Well, we know how to extract decimal digits in C:

```
lower_decimal_digit = num % 10
lower_2_decimal_digits = num % 100
```

and so on (we can also do this with a variable number of digits but that's not necessary here). Similarly, we can keep only the higher digits:

```
all_but_lower_decimal_digit = num / 10
all_but_lower_2_decimal_digits = num / 100
```

so in your case, the two commands:

```
int year = combined / 100;
int month = combined % 100;
```

do the trick. I'm sure you can proceed from there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was very helpful in understanding the logic.